# Bs4 only shows children of div classes but not of div ids

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I run a script with bs4 to login on a website and then try to grab information. The problem is that when i print soup.prettify, it only shows the children divs of div classes ( i see the div ids but not the other ones beneath them).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

secure_url = "https://portail.cje.qc.ca/pluriportail/pfr/LoginReq.srf?Etape=2&Login=1"
final_url = "https://portail.cje.qc.ca/pluriportail/pfr/Main.srf?P=MainAccueil"
payload = {
"NomLogin": "2190163",
"MotPasse": "\*\*\*\*\*" #password goes here
}


with requests.session() as s:
    s.post(secure_url, data=payload)
    r = s.get(final_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
    print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: The problem could be that the website depends on javascript, which `requests` cannot process.